# Msi for non windows universal application referencing winmd

Tags: c#, .net, windows-10-universal, windows-10-desktop

I have a .Net win forms application which uses Wi Fi Direct APIs available under Windows.Devices.WiFiDirect namespace.

I have referred to steps given in [Is it possible to use Wi-Fi Direct from a non Universal application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32439651/is-it-possible-to-use-wi-fi-direct-from-a-non-universal-application). The application works perfectly and I now need to package it into an installer (msi).

I am using the setup project available within visual studio 2015. However I get **ERROR: An error occurred while validating.  HRESULT = '80070057'** while trying to build it.

I suspect it is due to referencing the universal windows platform files i.e. winmd files. I have tried setting CopyLocal=false for those file, still no luck.

Anybody else faced similar issues? If yes - what was the solution?

Thanks.

Comment: Please provide us with the code so we can check it out and help you.

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32810288/43846) suggests **excluding** the winmd files.